# Intersection and difference of PostGIS data using R

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, r-sf

I am an absolute beginner in `PostgreSQL` and `PostGIS` (databases in general) but have a fairly good working experience in `R`. I have two multi-polygon data sets of vulnerable areas of India from two different sources - one is around 12gb and it's in `.gdb` format (let's call it `mygdb`) and the other is a shapefile around 2gb (let's call it `myshp`). I want to compare the two sets of vulnerability maps and generate some state-wise measures of fit using intersection (I), difference (D), and union (U) between the maps.
I would like to make use of `PostGIS` functionalities (via `R`) as neither `R` (crashes!) nor `qgis` (too slow) is efficient for this. To start with, I have uploaded both data sets in my `PostGIS` database. I used `ogr2ogr` in `R` to upload `mygdb`. But I am kind of stuck at this point. My idea is to split both polygon files by states and then apply other functions to get I, U and D. From my search, I think I can use `sf` functions like `st_split`, `st_intersect`, `st_difference`, and `st_union`. However, even after splitting, I would imagine that the file sizes will be still too large for r to process, so my questions are

1. Is my approach the best way forward?
2. How can I use `sf::st_` functions (e.g. `st_split`, `st_intersection`) without importing the data from database into R

There are some useful answers to previous relevant questions, like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64950/working-with-postgis-data-in-r/64990#64990) for example. But I find it hard to put the steps together from different links and any help with a dummy example would be great. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your data is a vector data. If you have loaded it to postrgres with postgis installed, they probably are splitted to different tables (points, lines, polygons) with several rows corresponding to features. There should be no problem loading them part by part to R for comparison. And yes, `sf()` library will be the good choice. Generally speaking, `st_` functions corresponds to `ST_` functions from Postgis.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind providing an example code to, for example, use st_intersection without importing the inputs locally?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try loading it as a stars proxy. It doesn't load the file to the memory, it applies it directly to the hard drive.

https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars2.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not answer for question sensu stricte, however in response to request in comment, an example of postgresql/postgis query for `ST_Intersection`. Based on `OSM` data in `postgresql` database imported with `osm2pgsql`:

```
WITH 
  highway AS (
    select osm_id, way from planet_osm_line where osm_id = 332054927), 
  dln AS (
    select osm_id, way from planet_osm_polygon where "boundary" = 'administrative' 
    and "admin_level" = '4' and "ref" = 'DS')
SELECT ST_Intersection(dln.way, highway.way) FROM highway, dln
```